# Setting up python control of google compute engine fails with: 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to setup Pythonic control of Google Compute Engine following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python-guide. When I run the script they give in that tutorial I get directed to a website where I auth my google account and then get a page that says:

> 1. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered   redirect URI

I think the URI needs to be something that's specific to my app but I can't for the life of me figure out where to get that URI in the developer console. Does anyone know where I can find it?